# Cannot filter in angularjs for Roman number

Tags: angularjs

I am unable to filter in angularjs for Roman number. I have four input area for search, image is below:

[image]

[image]

After select class 'I':-

Result:

```
Name  Class 
-----------
xyz     I
abc     II
ebc     VI
```

Accept:-

```
Name   Class
-------------
xyz     I
```

Code:

model is **ng-model="searchClass"**

```
<tr ng-repeat="defaulterList in defaulterLists| filter:searchText | filter:searchClass | filter:searchSection | filter:horsepowerFilter">
```

Even i try with attribute in filter, such as **filter:searchClass.class**  but not working

Filter Code:

```
     <tr ng-repeat="defaulterList in defaulterLists| filter:searchText | filter:searchClass | filter:searchSection | filter:horsepowerFilter">
           <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
           <td>{{defaulterList.admno}}</td>
           <td>{{defaulterList.name}}</td>
           <td>{{defaulterList.mobile_no}}</td>
           <td>{{defaulterList.class}}</td>
           <td>{{defaulterList.section}}</td>
           <td>{{defaulterList.total}}</td>
           <td><select ng-model="defaulterList.msgid" class="full-width"> <option value="">-select-</option><option ng-repeat="message in messages" value="{{message.id}}">{{message.title}}</option></select></td>
           <td><button class="btn-success btn-small" ng-click="sendSms(defaulterList)">Send SMS</button></td>

        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.defaulterLists = $scope.defaulterLists;
```

and change the the `searchText` to `$scope.data.searchText` . It should work now.

use the ng-repeat as

```
<tr ng-repeat="defaulterList in data.defaulterLists| filter:data.searchText | filter:data.searchClass | filter:data.searchSection | filter:data.horsepowerFilter">
```

Comment: searchText model working fine, but problem in searchClass model(select box). It cannot filter accurate value.

Comment: You could try it with _searchClass_, I just shown the example. When it is rendered using objects it should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was faced same problem.

Just change

From

**filter:searchClass**

To

**filter:searchClass:true**

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.romanize = function(num){
        if (!+num)
            return false;
        var digits = String(+num).split(""),
            key = ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM",
                   "","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC",
                   "","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"],
            roman = "",
            i = 3;
        while (i--)
            roman = (key[+digits.pop() + (i * 10)] || "") + roman;
        return Array(+digits.join("") + 1).join("M") + roman;
    }
```